# Using Pearson Moment Correlation For Establishing Validity Between Two Questionnaires

Tags: r, survey, psychometrics, research-design

I'm moderately new to psychometrics and test design, and I'm currently in the process of attempting to develop a questionnaire that measures soft skills (communication, collaboration, work ethic, leadership skills, etc...).

I would like to use an already existing, validated measure, which includes communication as one of its domains as a way to establish validity. The response options on the questionnaire I would like to design are ordinal in nature (ranging from 1-5).

My question is, would it be appropriate to use the Pearson product moment correlation as means of determining/confirming concurrent validity?

I'm currently using R version 4.1.1, and how I'm thinking of approaching the analysis is setting up my data so that the columns will include the domains from each questionnaire (e.g., "communication_valid_questionnaire" and "communication_to_be_validated"). I'm just wondering whether my methodology is sound, or whether I'm missing any crucial pieces of the puzzle.